# Macro for Excel not formatting correctly

Tags: vba, excel

I am recording a macro. There is a column I am trying to convert to number so I can use formula to calculate.

I use VBA code as follow:

```
Columns("D:D").NumberFormat="0.00"
```

and

```
Range("D:D").NumberFormat="0.00"
```

The cell itself is showing Number but I can still see the `!` sign next to the cell to ask if I want to convert from text to number.

I put my mouse over the cell and the message is `The number in the cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe.`

I am able to change the cell by click the `!` and change it from text to number. The formula in cell E works after I did it. I want to know if I can write a line in my macro to change this column D to be a number.

Comment: Avoid setting the `.NumberFormat` to full column references. The `.UsedRange` will adjust accordingly and you will be left with an oversized worksheet with a large filesize. Ctrl+End becomes useless.

Comment: @pnuts, i missed that. `macros` tag has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to do mass conversion of a column of text-numbers to numeric-numbers. The quickest, in my experience, is to hit it with the TextToColumns function:

```
 Range("D:D").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("D1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```